# How to call some method when user ends highlighting text inside another application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to call some method when user ends selecting/highlighting text inside another application:

```
OnUserEndsSelectionTextInAnotherApp(string selectedText)
{
    MessageBox.Show(selectedText);
}
```

Is there any similar method to OnUserEndsSelectionTextInAnotherApp in real world?
The second application is completely different process, like web browser, text editor or pdf reader.

Thanks.

Comment: You can setup hook but this requires WIN32API to be involved

Answer (score 1):

If the other app is coded by your own, you can use messages to communicate between your applications.

Here is a sample:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/ccee7ae6-75ca-4916-89cf-a099d12074a7

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer! I can't use this elegant way, becouse the trick is to get selection from any app (but not from some exotic ones).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup some sort of messaging layer between the two, is the second application in the same process (but another app domain) or is it completely different process ?

you could use .NET Remoting to signal messages between applications.

[This is good article about .NET Remoting which helped me in th past](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Remoting_Architecture.aspx?display=Print)

Comment: Thank you for help me detalize my question!

Comment: @mykola.rykov no probs, as you are new to StackOverflow, dont forget to vote for an answer :)

Comment: Don't worry, anvarbek raupov, I'll vote for your answer, if it really will help me) Now I'm working on it.

Comment: Yep, .NET Remoting is a powerfull mechanism, but it can't solve my problem.